# Boost.Hana JSON example: Difference between string and decltype(std::to_string(...))

Tags: c++, templates, boost-hana

I just read the [Boost.Hana tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection-json) but unfortunately got stuck very early. Could anybody explain to me why `to_json` for integers is implemented the way it is:

```
template <typename T>
auto to_json(T const& x) -> decltype(std::to_string(x)) {
  return std::to_string(x);
}
```

I thought that the return type would be simply equivalent to `std::string` but it is not. If you replace it with `std::string` the compiler complains about ambiguous function call. What is the difference between std::string and decltype(std::to_string(x))?

Comment: What is this [tag:blackmagic] tag about?

Comment: It is about black magic!

Comment: After thinking a bit about it I think it works the following way: If x is not an integral type (for which overloads of std::to_string(x) exist) the decltype expression is no longer valid and this causes substitution to fail. Therefore the compiler only selects this function for integral types.

Comment: @MaxLanghof It is kinda related but not exactly the same.

Comment: You are correct, this does indeed use SFINAE. The code in your question doesn't have any function overloading so that misled me, sorry.

Comment: @Nils you've got it, it enables SFINAE. You can answer yourself if you wish :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because SFINAE applies to the expression of the return type.

Not all types can be sent to `std::to_string`. This makes the expression of the return type resolve to a function that cannot be called with the provided argument. This is a subtitution failure and that  triggers SFINAE and the canditate is discarded.

When changing the return type to `std::string`, then the overload is not discarded, even if `std::to_string(x)` would not compile, so the function still takes part in the overload set, making the call ambiguous.

---

There are other places you could put the constraint. Here is some examples:

```
template<typename T> // in the non traitling return type
decltype(constrait) to_json() {}

// in the template parameters
template<typename T, decltype(void(constraint), 0) = 0>
auto to_json() -> std::string {}

// (less common) in the function parameters
template<typename T>
auto to_json(decltype(void(constraint), 0) = 0) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I now understand it. But having auto as return type and then the alternative return type syntax with -> looks awkward, is this a common technique to leverage SFINAE?

Comment: @Nils See the `auto f() -> int` as an alternative syntax for declaration. In fact, it would be nice to have a `func` keyword to replace the auto: `func f() -> int`. There are places that it makes the syntax much simpler, for example in member function returning a member type, or to constraint function like your example. I use this style everywhere because I try to be consistent and all function names are aligned :)

Comment: Hah then we would basically have Swifts function declaration syntax! I wonder how overload resolution for generic functions works there...